# How can I get a reference to a blazer control in code

Tags: blazor, .net-5

How can I get a reference to a blazer control in code.
I would like to change the control in code.

Comment: search "MSDN blazor @ref"

Comment: More specifically:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#capture-references-to-components-1

Comment: Only use references to get data or call methods, do not try to mutate the state of your child components. See the "ℹ️ Important" insert https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#capture-references-to-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use @ref on component declaration.

At next step, you have to define a variable with component type.

Now, you can access the component with variable.

```
<InputText @ref="PersonalNameTextbox" ...
```

In @code or razor.cs, define a variable:

```
InputText PersonalNameTextbox;
```

Example of access the component in afterRender, you can access them:

```
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
        PersonalNameTextbox.Value = "Untitled!";
    ...
}
```

Comment: PersonalNameTextbox will be null on `OnInitialized()` I find I have to use `OnFirstRender(bool)`

Comment: Thanks I will try it. I have other issues for the moment but this seems to be my answer.

Comment: Welcome bro, I'm glad hear you solved the problem.

Comment: Do NOT use component references to mutate the state of child components. See the "ℹ️ Important" insert https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#capture-references-to-components